# Getting SettingWithCopyWarning: when using .replace and .drop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to format two of my data frames and I am starting to get SettingWithCopyWarnings.  I know its warning me that I may be working with copies but I'm not sure how to fix that since I'm still new to Pandas.

Here is my code:

```
Bought = df2[df2['Quantity'] > 0] 
Sold = df2[df2['Quantity'] < 0] 
Bought.drop('Unit', axis = 1, inplace = True) 
Sold.drop('Unit', axis = 1, inplace = True) 
Bought['Account'].replace(to_replace = 'F1105', value = 'On', inplace = True) 
Bought['Account'].replace(to_replace = 'F1121', value = 'Off', inplace = True) 
Sold['Account'].replace(to_replace = 'F1105', value = 'On', inplace = True) 
Sold['Account'].replace(to_replace = 'F1121', value = 'Off', inplace = True)
Bought.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
Sold.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bought` and `Sold` are slices of the `DataFrame`; to get rid of the warning, start with:

```
Bought = df2[df2['Quantity'] > 0].copy() 
Sold = df2[df2['Quantity'] < 0].copy()
```